# Trying to move asp.net identity tables to my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

hello I'm trying to make an online store mvc applciation with view model and onion architecture. So in My interfaces folder I have my db context

```
class OnlineStoreDBContext:DbContext
    {
            public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
            public DbSet<CategoryLanguages> CategoryLanguages{ get; set; }
            public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
            public DbSet<ProductLanguages> ProductLanguages { get; set; }
            public DbSet<ProductCategories> ProuctCategories { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
            public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }


    }
```

And in my `web.config` of my mvc applciation I have the following  connection to my database

```
 <add name="OnlineStoreDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLexpress;Initial Catalog=OnlineStore;Integrated Security= true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

1.Now I try to  use asp.net identity in visual studio 2013 BUT I WANT THE TABLES WHICH 
IDENTITY CREATES TO BE IN MY DATABASE OnlineStore  which tables I create using the Code first Entity framework approach .

1. As I want to extend user class can you provide me with a simple way to add more more field for the user identity.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am very unfamiliar with MVC thing, sadly I can say.. But what I do in a similar situation was to create a connection string to your own DB in the web.config file but name it `"DefaultConnection"`

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLexpress;Initial Catalog=OnlineStore;Integrated Security= true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then I run the application and proceeded to Register and registered as a user... Then I saw that the schema was created in my DB. Then I supposed you can add your own tables and stuff in that DB..

> "1. As I want to extend user class can you provide me with a simple way to add more more field for the user identity."

If I haven't gotten it wrong you meant to add additional profile information. I am new a ASP.net Identity but with a quick search I found:

http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/adding-profile-data-in-Asp-Net-identity-using-visual-studio/

Hope I helped a bit..